# How to extend THREE.Mesh class for constructor function

Tags: javascript, three.js, extend

I'm playing around with Three.js and making a (simple!) model of the solar system. I am trying to make a constructor function to build out the planets and moons, this is what I've been trying so far but I get an error saying:

> setShadow() is not a function:

```
var body = function(size, color) {
  this.sphere = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(size, 32, 32), 
                               new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:color}))
  return this.sphere
}

body.prototype = Object.create(THREE.Mesh.prototype);
body.prototype.constructor = body;

body.prototype.setShadow = function() {
  this.sphere.castShadow = true
  this.sphere.receiveShadow = true
}
```

Alternatively, I've tried using `THREE.MESH.call(this, geometry, material)` where `THREE.SphereGeometry = geometry` and `THREE.MeshLambertMaterial = material` are defined outside the constructor function. Is this something in particular I need to worry about with Three.js or am I just approaching this incorrectly?

Edit: Alternative try ->

```
var body = function() {
      THREE.Mesh.call(this)
      return this
    }

    body.prototype.setShadow = function() {
      this.castShadow = true
      this.receiveShadow = true
      return this
    }
    body.prototype = Object.create(THREE.Mesh.prototype);
    body.prototype.constructor = body;

    var example = new body(new THREE.SphereGeometry(70, 32, 32), new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:this.getRandColor()}))
```

It seems like everything inherits correctly, but I'm confused as to why the setShadow function is not working correctly?

EDIT 2: actually got this error when trying `.call(this)` :

> this.updateMorphTargets is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a mistake in your constructor while extending the `THREE.Mesh` class.

Try like this:

```
var Body = function(size, color) {
    THREE.Mesh.call(
        this, 
        new THREE.SphereGeometry(size, 32, 32), 
        new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:color})
    );
}

Body.prototype = Object.create(THREE.Mesh.prototype);
Body.prototype.constructor = Body;
```

There is no need to return anything in the constructor since the object created will be automatically returned.

And in your `setShadow` method you should simply point to `this` since the properties [`castShadow`](http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Core/Object3D.castShadow) and [`receiveShadow`](http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Core/Object3D.receiveShadow) are direct properties of your newly created `Body` class (inherited from `THREE.Object3D` through `THREE.Mesh`).

```
Body.prototype.setShadow = function() {
    this.castShadow = true;
    this.receiveShadow = true;
}
```

It is also good practice to use capitals for the first character of your constructor so in my code I changed `body` to `Body`. Make sure you rename all other references accordingly.

**[Here a demonstration in a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ry04qqk5/)**

Comment: I implemented this solution and still get an error saying "Instance of Body".setShadow() is not a function. Works fine when I set castShadow and receiveShadow = true though.

Comment: @bpr I tried it [here in a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ry04qqk5/) and it works fine for me.

Comment: Apologies, I added setShadow to the prototype before setting body's prototype! Works now! Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

If you use this "function" method you will get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor Mesh cannot be invoked without 'new'

The best way to implement it now is using classes. Like this:

```js
class Body extends THREE.Mesh {
  constructor(size, color) {
    super(
      new THREE.SphereGeometry(size, 32, 32),
      new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
        color: color
      })
    )
  }

  setShadow() {
    this.castShadow = true
    this.receiveShadow = true
  }
}

const body = new Body(20, 0x000000)
console.log({castShadow: body.castShadow, receiveShadow: body.receiveShadow})
body.setShadow()
console.log({castShadow: body.castShadow, receiveShadow: body.receiveShadow})
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
```